# Is it safe to calculate pointer offset using nullptr?

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, nullptr

Suppose I have two pointers:

```
char* p1 = nullptr;
char* p2 = std::malloc( 4 );
std::size_t offset = p2 - p1;
```

Is it safe to get offset in this way? So far it works fine on my computer. But I'm wondering if the offset can exceed the maximum number of size_t such that this method fails?

Comment: Offset of what? And unless I 'm horribly mistaken, even the simple act of subtracting two unrelated pointers is not safe at all.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is signed -- use `std::ptrdiff_t`, not `std::size_t`, which is unsigned.

Comment: I can't see why this would ever make sense. I can see why you might want to find the difference between two pointers pointing into the same allocation of memory. But I can't see how it makes sense if one of the pointers doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: From the title, I assumed you'd want to talk about offset of field in a structure. In which the usual definition of [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) does use `nullptr`. But it is implementation defined. The implementer knows whether it's going to work in their compilers and use different definition if it isn't.

Comment: The motivation is that by doing the subtraction, p2 can be converted to the integral type, on which I'm able to employ bit hacks to eliminate one if-statement within my memory allocator (if enough space, return p2, else return nullptr). So the nullptr is basically the reference location that allows me to do that. I know this is not normal but to my surprise, it works on my gcc 4.8.3 20140624 with options -Wall -g -pedantic -std=c++11

Comment: I updated my answer to address your latest comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is undefined behavior, from the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `5.7` *Additive operators*:

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted,
>   the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements. The type of the result is an implementation-defined signed
>   integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as
>   std::ptrdiff_t in the  header (18.2). [...] Unless both
>   pointers point to elements of the same array object, or one past the
>   last element of the array object, the behavior is
>   undefined.<sup>82</sup>

Also as the reference mentions, the result is `std::ptrdiff_t` not `size_t`.

you can on the other hand add or subtract the value `0` which is covered in paragraph *7*:

> If the value 0 is added to or subtracted from a pointer value, the
>   result compares equal to the original pointer value. If two pointers
>   point to the same object or both point one past the end of the same
>   array or both are null, and the two pointers are subtracted, the
>   result compares equal to the value 0 converted to the type
>   std::ptrdiff_t.

If you want to convert a pointer to an integral value then you should use either [intptr_t or uinitptr_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer):

> ```
> intptr_t   integer type capable of holding a pointer
> uintptr_t  unsigned integer type capable of holding a pointer
> ```

For example:

```
uintptr_t ip = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>( p2 ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

No it is not safe. Basically the only thing you can do with null pointer is to compare it with another pointer. As for addition and subtraction one can only add or subtract zero to a null pointer, and subtract two null pointers - which may be useful in generic programming. Your case is undefined behaviour.

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/why-does-c-allow-arithmetic-on-null-poin/240001022), `C++ explicitly allows two kinds of pointer operations that are undefined in C: Adding zero to (or subtracting zero from) a null pointer yields a null pointer, and subtracting one null pointer from another one of the same type yields zero.`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by Wojtek, pointer arithmetic can and should only be done between related pointers. For example if you have e.g. `char* p3 = p2 + 4`, then you could do `p3 - p2` to get the difference between the two pointers, that would be legal.

However, things like

```
char* p4 = new char[4];
std::cout << p4 - p2 << '\n';
```

is ***not*** legal, as `p2` and `p4` are not *related*.